# How to remove index.php from url using web.config in iis server 8.0?

Tags: wordpress, web-config, iis-8

I have installed wordpress in iis server version 8.0. i have added custom structure in wordpress permalinks. server is not supporting permalinks. so i created web.config to remove index.php from the url.i cant able remove index.php. In root website i have web.config file. i  have created another config file to remove the index.php from the url in the sub folder. its not working. Is there any solution to remove it.

website url: http://www.cyz.com/blog/index.php/links
to 
url: http://www.cyz.com/blog/links

code in blog folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <add value="blog/index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WPurls" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="blog/index.php/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: if you can. Rename the index.php file. No need to remove it

Comment: In wp-content or any other folder @rajmathan.

Comment: In wp-content folder.

Comment: Ok i will try @rajmathan

Comment: not working. It shows 404 directory not found.

Comment: Can you brief me your question clearly?

Comment: Yeah sure . i have created wordpress blog in sub folder . i have tried to change the permalinks custom structure in wordpress after removing the index.php in custom structure. it shows 404 directory not found and i also tried to  remove index.php by using web.config. web.config is not working. Is there any possible solution for this issue.

Comment: If you want to redirect the page, create index.html file(bcoz, index.html loads before index.php) with redirect url inside the page loading part. I agree it is a dirty way of doing. Best way is using permalink at dashboard.